# Best practice for organizing web application logic using GitHub?

Tags: reactjs, git, github, google-cloud-functions

I'm in the process of setting up the development environment for a new web application, that will ultimately have a mobile component added. This is being built as a React Front-end Application that will use Google Cloud Functions for the back-end.

For source control, issue tracking, project management, I'll be using GitHub.

My question is, should I try to have a separate repository for the back-end Cloud Functions and one for the React-app front-end? Or Is it just easier to have a single application/repository and have the Google Functions live in the Functions folder?

When we add the mobile component, it will be a separate application/repository..but curious if there is any benefit to try and keep server cloud functions in their own repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to separate concerns, which means having your react front-end application separate from your back-end cloud Functions.

Comment: Ok, thx for the reply. I have a single firebase project that holds both functions and code, so I guess this just means creating separate folders for react app , and one for functions and then syncing

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is opinion-based prone.

In my opinion, I would strongly recommend anyone to not start a project using separate repositories unless there is a good reason to do so.

Separating concerns in folders within a repo should suffice. See [this discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194822/when-to-separate-a-project-in-multiple-subprojects) for more background.